# Hide/Unhide groups of cells in excel with Button

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a group of cells B32 till R32 length and B32 to B51 breadth. I want to keep this block hidden at the start when the sheet is opened. I have named this block as 'Analysis'.

There is a button in the sheet. When the button is pressed, I want to unhide that block. I am new to Excel Vba. I would like to know the syntax/code for doing this operation.

Thanks in advance.

Ananda

Comment: This is an easily google-able answer, I think.

Comment: The code I checked out in google isn't working.

Comment: Which code are you using? You didn't mention that in your original question.

Comment: I don't think you can hide a block of cells - you would have to hide the entire column or row. If by 'hide' you mean you want to make the data invisible, try colouring the text white instead?

Comment: please show us your code, and we'll help you improve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant just hide an area like MattCrum has mentioned.
You have 3 choices as far as I am concerned

---

Now, just make sure you have something(data - not empty cells) in the `Range 32:51` and your main sheet is either called `Sheet1` or change `Sheet1` in the code to suit your worksheets name

1)
in `VBE ( Visual Basic Editor )` double click `ThisWorkbook` in the `project explorer` and paste this code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(32 & ":" & 51).hidden = True
End Sub
```

Right click on the folder `Modules` and `Insert` a new `Module`, then paste this code

```
Sub unhide()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(32 & ":" & 51).hidden = False
End Sub
```

Now, add a button on the spreadsheet, right click and assign macro called `unhide` to it.

Save changes and save your workbook as *.xlsm file

Notice when you open the workbook now, rows 32 to 51 are hidden. Clicking the button will unhide them.

---

2) You can change the font color to white to `"hide"` the contents.

Follow step 1, and replace

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(32 & ":" & 51).hidden = True
```

with this

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B32:R51").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
```

and the code in the `Module` ( the `unhide` subroutine )with

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B32:R51").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
```

Now, everything works similar to step 1 except your are `"hiding"`(changing) the font color instead of hiding rows. Not a great approach, but if it works for you then cool

---

3) Follow step 1 and replace the code under `ThisWorkbook` with

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "hiddenSheet"
    Set hs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
    hs.Visible = xlSheetHidden

    ws.Range("B32:R51").Select
    Selection.Copy

    With hs
        .Activate
        .Range("B32").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

    ws.Activate
    ws.Rows(32 & ":" & 51).Delete

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Call deleteHidden(Worksheets.Count)
End Sub
```

And the code in the `Module1` with

```
Option Explicit
Public ws As Worksheet, hs As Worksheet

Sub unhide()
    With hs
        .Activate
        .Rows("32:51").Select
        Selection.Copy
    End With
    With ws
        .Activate
        .Rows("32:32").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End With
End Sub

Sub deleteHidden(num&)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets(num).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set hs = Nothing
End Sub
```